# How to test whether an Angular mat-nav-list contains an element?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

I'd like to check whether an Angular `mat-nav-list` contains an element.

I'm able to select it with `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.items'))`, but I'm not sure how to check whether it contains anything.

My template:

```html
<mat-nav-list class="items">
    <a class="list-item" mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <app-item-display [item]="item"></app-item-display>
    </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

In my test I inject 1 item and expect it to render.
While component does contain an item, I'd like to check whether its rendered in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try queryAll

```
const items= fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.list-item'));
```

and then you can check if length is correct after faking items list

```
expect(items.length).toBe(2) // or your fake data length
```